# Error in Yii2 ajax file upload using kartik file input

Tags: php, ajax, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

Am performing a file upload using the kartik yii2 extension in ajax

This is an implementation of a court system where a case can have many evidences and one uploads them

Models
Case code:

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        [['ref_no', 'case_description', 'raised_on', 'status', 'raised_by', 'updated_on', 'case_type'], 'required'],
        [['raised_on', 'updated_on'], 'safe'],
        [['ref_no', 'status', 'raised_by', 'case_type'], 'string', 'max' => 100],
        [['case_description'], 'string', 'max' => 300]
    ];
}

/**
 * @inheritdoc
 */
public function attributeLabels()
{
    return [
        'ref_no' => 'Ref No',
        'case_description' => 'Case Description',
        'raised_on' => 'Raised On',
        'status' => 'Status',
        'raised_by' => 'Raised By',
        'updated_on' => 'Updated On',
        'case_type' => 'Case Type',
    ];
}


public function getEvidences()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Evidence::className(), ['case_ref' => 'ref_no']);
}
```

Evidences model code:

```
    public function rules()
{
    return [
        [['case_ref', 'saved_by', 'saved_on', 'evidence_type'], 'required'],
        [['saved_on'], 'safe'],
        [['path'], 'safe'],
        [['case_ref', 'saved_by'], 'string', 'max' => 100],
        [['evidence_type'], 'string', 'max' => 50],
        [['path'], 'file']
    ];
}

/**
 * @inheritdoc
 */
public function attributeLabels()
{
    return [
        'case_ref' => 'Case Ref',
        'saved_by' => 'Saved By',
        'saved_on' => 'Saved On',
        'id' => 'ID',
        'evidence_type' => 'Evidence Type',
        'path' => 'Path',
    ];
}

public function getCaseRef()
{
    return $this->hasOne(Cases::className(), ['ref_no' => 'case_ref']);
}
```

In my controller action create( case controller)
code:

```
    public function actionCreate()
{
   $model = new Cases();
    $evidence = new Evidence();

    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->save()) {
        return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->ref_no]);
    } 
    else {
        return $this->render('profile', [
            'model' => $model,'evidence'=>$evidence,
        ]);
    }
}
```

The view that is the profile rendered by the create 
code:

```
    <?php $form = ActiveForm::begin([
            'options' => ['enctype'=>'multipart/form-data']
        ]); ?> 
<?php   echo $form->field($evidence, 'path')->widget(FileInput::classname(), [ 
                    'options' => ['accept' => 'image/*','multiple' => true],
                    'pluginOptions' => [
                 'browseIcon' => '<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-camera"></i> ',
                    'showPreview' => true,
                    'showCaption' => true,
                    'showRemove' => true,
                    'showUpload' => true,
                    'filename'=>'kagumo',
                    'browseLabel' =>  'Insert Evidence',
                   'uploadUrl' => Url::to(['cases/upload']),
                    'maxFileCount' => 10
                    ]
        ]
        );?>
<?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
```

The upload action in the cases controller as specified by the url in the file input cases/upload

```
public function actionUpload(){


   //print_r($_FILES['images']);

if (empty($_FILES['name'])) {
    echo json_encode(['error'=>'No files found for pload.']); 
    // or you can throw an exception 
    return; // terminate
}else{
    echo  json_encode(['error'=>'files available for upload']);
}
 }
```

The above always returns the error no file for upload indicating that file data isn't passed onto the controller

Comment: you use model _Evidence_ in view form (in _$form->field($evidence, 'path')....._)  so you should have _$_FILES['Evidence']['name']_ instead of _$_FILES['name']_. try _print\_r($_FILES)_ to debug

Comment: Thanks I found out that you need to pass a property of name in the options of the view so as to overwrite the default property.(that is adding 'name'=>'name'